# simple-salesforce bulk query takes hours for a simple soql

Tags: python, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

My bulk query has been taking hours in production today. Before this, it takes only a few minutes. Just wondering what might be the issue?

This takes 2 hours (This is a test query on production)

```
sf.bulk.__getattr__("Account").query("SELECT ID FROM Account limit 1", lazy_operation=True)
```

This takes 3 seconds

```
sf.query_all("SELECT ID FROM Account limit 1")
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Bulk API is asynchronous by design. While two hours is an extremely long delay, in my experience, the Bulk API may take considerable time to execute a query and make results available. That time is dependent on many factors, including the overall load on your org and the instance where it is hosted. The Bulk API's saving grace is that it can do so even if the query returns enormous numbers of records.

If you continue to see extreme performance delays in the Bulk API, open a support case. There's not much else you can do.

For small data volumes, using the REST API (via `query_all()`, here) is much, much faster nearly 100% of the time. I've implemented multiple integrations that dynamically select the Bulk or REST APIs based on data volume to attempt to maximize performance.

---

Side note: you don't need the `__getattr__()` call, just do

```
sf.bulk.Account.query(...)
```

Comment: how do you know dynamically how much data volume there will be

Comment: Also, if querying an object with many fields I get the uri too long error, which forces to always use bulk api

Comment: @West You run a count query.